# When are $m, 24m+1, 48m+1$ perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to solve the cannonball problem, which asks for a positive integer $k$ such that the sum of the first $k$ squares is itself a square. $k=1$ and $k=24$ are the only solutions, but that seems really hard to prove, so I restricted myself to the case where $6$ divides $k$. I got that $k=24m$, and that $m$, $24m+1$ and $48m+1$ are all squares. Obviously, $m=1$ works, and it leads to $k=24$, but is there a quick way to show that $m=1$ is the unique solution?

Comment: $m=0$ also works, if you drop the strict positivity condition.

Comment: If $m=a^2$, $24m+1=b^2$, $48m+1=c^2$, then $\frac{c}{b}\approx \sqrt 2$ and $\frac{c}{4a}\approx\sqrt {3}$.

Comment: ^Does this lead to a contradiction?

Comment: I don't think the case 6 divides $k$ will be any easier than the general case.